# Auto remove old records from SQL table on insert request

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking for a solution to auto-remove the oldest record of a table when a new record is inserted :

I want maximum 3 different records with different data but same userID, and I would like to make my table automatically remove the oldest record when a new one is inserted.

I think it's clear enough to be understood.. If not, I'll try to explain.
Sorry for bad english, not my main language

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like an XY-problem. Please tell us about X. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem - Are you looking for a cleanup strategy?

Comment: Sound like an `ON AFTER INSERT` hook?

Comment: The table has a timestamp column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try this kind of request ?

```
delete 
from table_name 
where id not in ( 
    select id 
    from table_name 
    order by timestamp_column desc 
    limit 0,3
)
```